# Bash root crontab script hangs and doesn't run again

Tags: linux, bash, docker, cron

**UPDATE**: I replaced **run-one** in `*/30 * * * * run-one /opt/scripts/staleFile.sh` with 
 `run-this-one` and the log updated! It appears run-one was holding it back. I'm not sure how locks in run-one are handled, but something in my script was preventing it from releasing the lock. I searched `ps aux | grep [script-name]` and `ps aux | grep [PID of original stuck cron command from syslog]` but didn't see that the script was actually stuck, so I think it's a problem with run-one. I use run-one in several other cron scripts and have yet to have a problem. If anyone has any suggestions as to what is tripping it up, I am all ears. **/UPDATE**

I have a bash root crontab script that runs every 30 minutes to check for a nfs stale file handle, and fix it by remounting fstab if there is a stale handle. This occurs every time I move data onto the nfs share, and again around 7AM the following day, as when data is moved onto the share it is first loaded onto a cache drive, and then moved to the HDDs in the early morning. It appears to complete successfully based on logs (pasted below the script), but **takes forever to complete (1hr51m)** based on logfile timestamps, and **will not run again if it encounters a stale handle and fixes it**. If the same script is simply run as root, i.e. *"sudo ./staleFile.sh"* it completes both quickly (under a minute), and as intented.

I have docker containers that depend on a mergerfs mount combining local data and data from my nfs share, which is why I stop those while the script is running.

**The following is the relevant excerpt from my sudo crontab**:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

*/30 * * * * run-one /opt/scripts/staleFile.sh
```

**The following is the script in question**:

```
#!/bin/bash
logFile="/av/misc/logs/stale.log" #REMEMBER TO CHANGE!
exec &>> "$logFile"

# Exit if not being run by root user.
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then echo "script must be run as root. exiting..."; exit 1; fi

# Get time for log
now="$(/usr/bin/date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')"

# Check for stale file handle, exit script if no problems
if ls /mnt/movies &>/dev/null; then :; else mov=1; fi
if ls /mnt/TV     &>/dev/null; then :; else tv=1; fi
if [[ -z $mov && -z $tv ]]; then echo "$now: ok"; exit 0; fi

echo "Stale file handle...fixing"
echo "----------START----------"
printf "DATE: %s\n" "$now"

if [[ "$mov" && -z "$tv" ]]; then #check if just movies nfs share
    echo "STALE NFS MOVIE FILE HANDLE. FIXING..."
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop radarr
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop rutorrent
    echo "unmounting /av/mergerfs/movies"
    umount /av/mergerfs/movies
    systemctl stop plexmediaserver.service
    echo "unmounting /mnt/movies"
    umount /mnt/movies
    echo "remounting fstab"
    mount -a
    systemctl start plexmediaserver.service
    echo "remounting /av/mergerfs/movies"
    mergerfs -o allow_other,minfreespace=75G,async_read=false,use_ino,func.getattr=newest,category.action=all,category.create=ff,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,nonempty /av/movies=RW:/mnt/movies=RO /av/mergerfs/movies
    echo "relaunching docker containers"
    mergMovies=$(find /av/mergerfs/movies/* -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
    mergTV=$(find /av/mergerfs/tv/* -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
    if [ "$mergMovies" -gt 1000 ]; then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d radarr; fi
    if [[ $mergTV -gt 200 && $mergMovies -gt 1000 ]]; then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d rutorrent; fi
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml restart reverse
    echo "finished!"
    exit 0
elif [[ -z "$mov" && "$tv" ]]; then #check if just tv nfs share
    echo "STALE NFS TV FILE HANDLE. FIXING..."
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop sonarr
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop rutorrent
    echo "unmounting /av/mergerfs/*..."
    umount /av/mergerfs/tv
    systemctl stop plexmediaserver.service
    echo "unmounting /mnt/[services]"
    umount /mnt/TV
    echo "remounting fstab"
    mount -a
    systemctl start plexmediaserver.service
    echo "remounting /av/mergerfs/tv..."
    mergerfs -o allow_other,minfreespace=75G,async_read=false,use_ino,func.getattr=newest,category.action=all,category.create=ff,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,nonempty /av/tv=RW:/mnt/TV=RO /av/mergerfs/tv
    echo "relaunching docker containers"
    mergTV=$(find /av/mergerfs/tv/* -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
    mergMovies=$(find /av/mergerfs/movies/* -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
    if [ "$mergTV" -gt 200 ];      then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d sonarr; fi
    if [[ $mergTV -gt 200 && $mergMovies -gt 1000 ]]; then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d rutorrent; fi
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml restart reverse
    echo "finished!"
    exit 0
elif [[ "$mov" && "$tv" ]]; then #must be both
    echo "STALE NFS MOVIE & TV FILE HANDLE. FIXING..."
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop radarr
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop sonarr
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml stop rutorrent
    echo "unmounting /av/mergerfs/BOTH..."
    umount /av/mergerfs/movies
    umount /av/mergerfs/tv
    systemctl stop plexmediaserver.service
    echo "unmounting /mnt/BOTH"
    umount /mnt/movies
    umount /mnt/TV
    echo "remounting fstab"
    mount -a
    systemctl start plexmediaserver.service
    echo "remounting /av/mergerfs/movies..."
    mergerfs -o allow_other,minfreespace=75G,async_read=false,use_ino,func.getattr=newest,category.action=all,category.create=ff,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,nonempty /av/movies=RW:/mnt/movies=RO /av/mergerfs/movies
    echo "remounting /av/mergerfs/tv..."
    mergerfs -o allow_other,minfreespace=75G,async_read=false,use_ino,func.getattr=newest,category.action=all,category.create=ff,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,nonempty /av/tv=RW:/mnt/TV=RO /av/mergerfs/tv
    #restart docker containers, but check if mergerfs mount was successful based on number of files
    echo "relaunching docker containers"
    mergMovies=$(find /av/mergerfs/movies/* -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
    mergTV=$(find /av/mergerfs/tv/* -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
    if [ "$mergTV" -gt 200 ];      then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d sonarr; fi
    if [ "$mergMovies" -gt 1000 ]; then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d radarr; fi
    if [[ $mergTV -gt 200 && $mergMovies -gt 1000 ]]; then docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml up -d rutorrent; fi
    docker-compose -f /opt/docker-compose.yml restart reverse
    echo "finished!"
    exit 0
fi
```

**The following is an excerpt from the logs** (the weird characters are from docker highlighting "done" in green in the console, everything looks normal when viewed on the console):

```
2020/06/30 04:00: ok
2020/06/30 04:30: ok
2020/06/30 05:00: ok
2020/06/30 05:30: ok
2020/06/30 06:00: ok
2020/06/30 06:30: ok
2020/06/30 07:00: ok
Stale file handle...fixing
----------START----------
DATE: 2020/06/30 07:30
STALE NFS TV FILE HANDLE. FIXING...
Stopping sonarr ... 
[1A[2K
Stopping sonarr ... [32mdone[0m
[1BStopping rutorrent ... 
[1A[2K
Stopping rutorrent ... [32mdone[0m
[1Bunmounting /av/mergerfs/*...
unmounting /mnt/[services]
remounting fstab
remounting /av/mergerfs/tv...
relaunching docker containers
Starting sonarr ... 
[1A[2K
Starting sonarr ... [32mdone[0m
[1BStarting rutorrent ... 
[1A[2K
Starting rutorrent ... [32mdone[0m
[1BRestarting reverse ... 
[1A[2K
Restarting reverse ... [32mdone[0m
[1Bfinished!
```

As seen in the logs, **after the script returns "finished!" it no longer runs again on the scheduled following half-hour**. Also, the timestamp on the logfile is 8:51AM, meaning it took forever (1hr 51m) to complete in the first place. I have other root crontab scripts that continue to run as scheduled.

Comment: the syslog shows it is still trying to run. `Jun 30 13:00:01 ISOTHERMICX CRON[700109]: (root) CMD (run-one /opt/scripts/staleFile.sh)` Also, I checked ps aux to see if the whole script is hanging and run-one is preventing it from re-executing, but there is nothing when `ps aux | grep staleFile.sh`

Comment: I would add some serious `wait` and/or `sleep` instructions there. E.g. mount and systemctl can take some time to do their jobs. Also, I would echo different exit messages for all cases, for better debugging - ymmv.

Comment: Or e.g. after doing a `mount`, explicitly check if the thing you want mounted actually *is* mounted.

Comment: @Roadowl `mount` won't wait for a response? meaning, the script continues even if it is unfinished?

Comment: No, mount won't wait till all drives have been mounted. If they are physical drives that takes time, try it once on your machine and watch /var/log/kern.log 'do' its thing; that can easily take seconds with terabyte drives. Just check /proc/mounts to see if the thing you want (re)mounted is actually mounted now.

Comment: Personal note: all this (re)mounting etc.from a cron job makes make nervous anyway. What if a process is running 'on' one of the mount points? Then the unmount will fail.

Comment: @Roadowl That's why I stop the docker containers and plex service. No other processes use these mounts. The /mnt mounts are nfs, /av/mergerfs are mergerfs (fuse)

Comment: @Roadowl Also, thanks for your help. I modified the script to just notify to a file when there's a stale mount, and I'll run the rest manually when I see the notif. The only disruptions this stale thing causes is to radarr and sonarr, which isn't a big deal. Plex seems to handle stale files just fine, as I can stream things even when the stale thing prevents me from `cd`'ing into the mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the cron from:

`*/30 * * * * run-one /opt/scripts/staleFile.sh`

to this

`*/30 * * * * su - root run-one /opt/scripts/staleFile.sh`

Add the su -root to run the script as a root

Comment: The script is already being executed as root by being in root's crontab. It passes my `if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then echo "script must be run as root. exiting..."; exit 1; fi` check, when it actually runs.